# Embeded Web View in Android Application

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to create my own browser, such that it will use Web View to display a page of my choosing. My issue is that, although I can get Web View working as a separate application (by following the tutorial at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html), I can't get it to display within my application.

I thought that just creating a WebViewer (my implementation of Web View) would run the program.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      

    WebViewer wv = new WebViewer();
}
```

(WebViewer was set up to display google automatically), but all I get is a white box when I run the program. The main.xml file has a WebViewer object, and internet rights are established in the manifest.

When that didn't work, I tried just implementing Android's Web Viewer directly.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      

    WebView wv = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(wv);
    wv.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.org/");
}
```

That just crashes the program as soon as I try to run it.

I know I'm very new at this, and perhaps I'm just missing something small, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you tell us what's inside your logcat ? Maybe you need to put Internet Permission ?

Answer (score 0):

Going back to your first attempt, what is in your main.xml? Most of the time, you should have your Views in your XML (like in the example you linked to) and you should be instantiating your views with findViewById(), (also in the example). The second attempt may be crashing due to the WebView not having any layout parameters, but I'm not 100% sure. Why not build more off of the example?

Comment: When I started playing around with Web View, I pulled directly off that example, and created by own viewer using Web View. When I went to try to put that in something else, I just sort of assumed that I should take the class that I had created implementing Web View, and put it into another class. I suppose somewhere along the way, it would have been simpler to just put android's own web view into the new program, but I was apparently trying to make it complicated.

Comment: My main.xml is basically an outside Linear layout containing 3 inner linear layouts (with buttons/text boxes), and the webviewer. (I would post the code here, but I don't think it will give me that many words....)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to find the WebView in your onCreate and do the loadUrl on that.  You are also setting you content view once and then again.  Unless you are doing something really crazy you should only really need to that once.  Try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      

    WebView wv = findViewById(R.id.my_wv_id);
    wv.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.org/");
}
```

The twitter android sdk actually has a really nice example on how to do this: https://github.com/sugree/twitter-android-sdk/blob/master/twitter/src/com/sugree/twitter/TwDialog.java .

Comment: I tried this code, with the name of the element in place of my_wv_id. No dice. Still crashes, and has me force quit. That example looks super useful though. I'll try to pull from that!

Comment: Perhaps you forget add INTERNET permission?